# Java Error when scanning .txt file: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, error-handling

```
public Ticketmachine(boolean openAutomat, String nameMachine, int ticketprice)
{
    if(openMachine == true){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(nameMachine+".txt");
        String x = reader.nextLine();
        String y = reader.nextLine();
        String z = reader.nextLine();
        int u = Integer.parseInt(x);
        int v = Integer.parseInt(y);
        int w = Integer.parseInt(z);
        price = u;
        paid = v;
        sum = w;
    }
```

Every time I open a new class and put openMachine to true,
it should take three numbers from the first three lines of a .txt file
and put them into the variables x, y and z. 
These will be converted into the datatype integer and then
they will be put into the variables price, paid and sum.
Now what happens instead when i make openMachine true,
is that it shows the folllowing error:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

and marks the ninth line:

```
int v = Integer.parseInt(y);
```

Would be nice if someone is able to tell me the answer :D

Comment: Please post your input file. It looks like there aren't 3 lines in your input file.

Comment: Are you sure there are at least 3 lines in that txt file? You should be checking that before attempting to store the values.

Comment: are you sure that's the line it marks? It seems to be an error with your `Scanner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you construct a Scanner using a String, then it uses that String as the source. You need to pass a File object to the Scanner constructor.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(nameMachine+".txt"));
```